# Graph plotting app

Tags: webapp-rec

Is there a good graph plotting app?

E.g. I have some stuff like:

```
Browsers from 2010-06-09 to 2010-06-16
Firefox: 45100
MSIE: 12779
Chrome: 10843
Opera: 3286
Safari: 5472
Android: 302
Browsers from 2010-06-16 to 2010-06-23
Firefox: 42845
MSIE: 10125
Chrome: 7789
Opera: 2814
Safari: 6473
Android: 462
Browsers from 2010-06-23 to 2010-06-30
Firefox: 46036
MSIE: 15679
Chrome: 9622
Opera: 2513
Safari: 6433
Android: 951
Konqueror: 96
```

or some such data, and it can plot a graph for me?

Not just for this but any kind of data?

Prefer free site if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **Google Docs** - Spreadsheet to create a graph based on data you insert. Probably not on a dynamic, real time scale, but you can still get a graph out, just like you could in Excel.

Comment: Actually I got a nicer graph with this than I could get with Excel. The export image only gives a small sized image though.

Comment: If you're talking about exporting the image of your chart in Google Docs/Spreadsheets, you could always take a screenshot of the chart, if the export is failing.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Google-Chart-API](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/charttools/index.html) to draw dynamically charts (up to a size of 300,000 pixels, 1000px max in each dimension). You can play with the API [over at the playground](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/chart/docs/chart_playground.html).

this is an example of the data you have given:

[image]

How to create such chart?

1. Copy the URL of the diagram above
2. Go over to [the playground](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/apis/chart/docs/chart_playground.html).
3. Put the URL of the diagram into the URL field
4. It will show you the parts of the URL in a nicer way

Then you can play around with the parameters:

```
cht=bvs:nda
chs=250x150
chd=t:45100,42845,46036|
    12779,10125,15679|
    10843,7789,9622|
    3286,2814,2513|
    5472,6473,6433|
    302,462,951|
chco=aaaaff,aaffaa,ffcccc,ccccff,ccffcc
chds=0,100000
chld=Firefox|
    MSIE|
    Chrome|
    Opera|
    Safari|
    Android
chbh=a
```

There is also an online wizard for it. Check it out at http://imagecharteditor.appspot.com/.

Read the documentation about the parameters. For example, the "chld" parameter is to create labels for the data. I was not in the mood to fine tune it to the end, so you do not have any labels for "which color represents what".

Comment: awfully developer-y though...

Comment: oh so true, but ... for those who do not feel the pain ... :)

Comment: I don't see how to go from the data to the graph. Could you explain what you did?

Comment: OK, I see it has to be done via the URL. It is not suitable for uploading a lot of data and getting a graph back. However, it seems like a really fun thing.

Comment: via POST you can upload 16k of data.

Comment: Ah, OK, I want to study this more. Sounds good.